# How to see the stats about workers in Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

We can get some information about sidekiq's status via [its API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API). There's not an API method for workers.

I want to know how many workers a certain class is running. For example I have a class named `FooStreamer.rb` and it's performed with `perform_async` method. I want to know how many workers it is running at the current time.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is documented in the wiki here https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by Mike (creator of sidekiq) with the following commit:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/c606dd4fde8cdc795d2c750d211a74bf1b380217

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq comes with a Sinatra web interface which you can access thru mydomain.com/sidekiq. You just need to mount it as per these instructions (it differs depending on whether you use Passenger or Unicorn)

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

There's no API that I know of, but you can easily iterate through the Redis keys that stores the Sidekiq information to count the number of workers working on a particular queue

```
workers = redis.smembers("workers")

workers.each do |worker|
        tokens = worker.split(":")
        machine = tokens[0]
        pid = tokens[1].split("-")[0]
        key = "worker:" + pid
        obj = redis.get(key)

        #obj will contain information on what queue this worker is processing
end
```

Comment: I couldn't get it working. In my case it constantly shows 4 workers even when no worker is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/phstc/sidekiq-statsd and check the stats using a Graphite.